# String encode/decode issue - missing character from end

Tags: python, python-2.7, encode, pyodbc, netezza

I am having `NVARCHAR` type column in my database. I am unable to convert the content of this column to plain string in my code. (I am using `pyodbc` for the database connection).

```
# This unicode string is returned by the database
>>> my_string = u'\u4157\u4347\u6e65\u6574\u2d72\u3430\u3931\u3530\u3731\u3539\u3533\u3631\u3630\u3530\u3330\u322d\u3130\u3036\u3036\u3135\u3432\u3538\u2d37\u3134\u3039\u352d'

# prints something in chineese 
>>> print my_string
䅗䍇湥整⵲㐰㤱㔰㜱㔹㔳㘱㘰㔰㌰㈭㄰〶〶ㄵ㐲㔸ⴷㄴ〹㔭
```

The closest I have gone is via encoding it to `utf-16` as:

```
>>> my_string.encode('utf-16')
'\xff\xfeWAGCenter-04190517953516060503-20160605124857-4190-5'
>>> print my_string.encode('utf-16')
��WAGCenter-04190517953516060503-20160605124857-4190-5
```

But the actual value that I need as per the value store in database is:

```
WAGCenter-04190517953516060503-20160605124857-4190-51
```

I tried with encoding it to `utf-8`, `utf-16`, `ascii`, `utf-32` but nothing seemed to work.

Does anyone have the idea regarding what I am missing? And how to get the desired result from the `my_string`.

**Edit**: *On converting it to `utf-16-le`, I am able to remove unwanted characters from start, but still one character is missing from end*

```
>>> print t.encode('utf-16-le')
WAGCenter-04190517953516060503-20160605124857-4190-5
```

*On trying for some other columns, it is working. **What might be the cause of this intermittent issue?***

Comment: You're seeing a byte-order mark (BOM)

Comment: @brianpck Byte order mark at the start  + missing 1 at the end. I am investigating about *Byte order mark* right now. Any idea why `1` is missing from last?

Comment: The characters in `my_string` *are* cjk code points so thats unlikely to be whats actually returned from the `nvarchar` field?  If possible could always read it as a `varchar` with a cast `select cast(field as varchar(xxx)) ...`

Comment: The BOM is added by the 'utf-16' codec and not likely in the raw data.

Comment: @AlexK. : My query is like `SELECT UNIQUE(MY_ID) FROM MY_TABLE;` and on printing `resultset`, i get `[(u'\u4157\u4347\u6e65\u6574\u2d72\u3430\u3931\u3530\u3731\u3539\u3533\u3631\u3630\u3530\u3330\u322d\u3130\u3036\u3036\u3135\u3432\u3538\u2d37\u3134\u3039\u352d', )]`

Comment: On converting it to utf-16-le, I am able to remove unwanted characters from start, but still one character is missing from end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a major problem in your database definition, in the way you store values in it, or in the way you read values from it. I can only explain what you are seeing, but neither why nor how to fix it without:

- the type of the database
- the way you input values in it
- the way you extract values to obtain your *pseudo unicode* string
- the actual content if you use direct (*native*) database access

What you get is an ASCII string, where the 8 bits characters are grouped by pair to build 16 bit unicode characters in little endian order. As the expected string has an odd numbers of characters, the last character was (irremediably) lost in translation, because the original string ends with `u'\352d'` where 0x2d is ASCII code for `'-'` and 0x35 for `'5'`. Demo:

```
def cvt(ustring):
    l = []
    for uc in ustring:
        l.append(chr(ord(uc) & 0xFF)) # low order byte
        l.append(chr((ord(uc) >> 8) & 0xFF)) # high order byte
    return ''.join(l)

cvt(my_string)
'WAGCenter-04190517953516060503-20160605124857-4190-5'
```

Comment: I admit this does not answer the question, but it is the best I can do with the given informations, and it is too elaborated for a comment

Comment: I am using `Netezza` as a database engine. and I am unable to encode it to `ascii`. I have configured my `pyodbc` for `utf-16`. Let me know what additional details you need? Thanks for the explanation. I know there is something wrong, but I do not know where to check. Also, this database I am using belongs to different team, I can only only change configuration at my project level.

Comment: @user7001260: could you configure pyodbc for a latin1 encoding? Latin1 just contains the 256 first codes of unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, I was using `UTF-16` in my `odbcinst.ini` file where as I had to use `UTF-8` format of character encoding.

Earlier I was changing it as an `OPTION` parameter while making connection to `PyODBC`. But later changing it in `odbcinst.ini` file fixed the issue.